# C# MySqlAdapter Fill ошибка: Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

У меня есть удалённая база данных и в ней таблица **" subject "**. После того, как я убрал у неё столбец **" id "**, который был *Primary Key Autoincrement*, мой C# скрипт стал кидать ошибку **" Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре "** на запрос по типу **" SELECT * FROM subject "**. При этом аналогичный запрос в phpMyAdmin и в MySQLWorkBench работает корректно.

Скриншот таблицы **subject:**
[image: Скриншот таблицы **subject:**]

Код:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace KuzCodeSchoolBot
{
    class Program
    {
        const string connectString = "Server = remotemysql.com; Database = Xm8ONq0tHG; User = Xm8ONq0tHG; Password = rcUONxQHd6; Port = 3306; Charset = utf8";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
            var res = DBQueries.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM subject", connection);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(res.Rows[i]["name"]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("All done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, MySqlConnection connection)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                adapter.Fill(table); // ----> ТУТ ОШИБКА! <---- //
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();                
            }

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Любопытно. Смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41930040/5045688) и [здесь](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/to-overcome-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-exception-in-mysql/).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, у меня всё получилось. Самое забавное, что я уже видел эти странички. У меня все поля стояли на Table Default, а таблица на utf8-generic-ci, но почему-то,когда я поменял эти поля вручную на ту же кодировку, всё сработало. Правда теперь почему-то не могу сделать с этой таблицей Foreign Key

Comment: С последним я просто протупил... Там просто тоже нужно было поменять поля на нужную кодировку. Проблема всего этого в том, что кодировка таблицы не хочет применяться к колонкам...